# Как получить разные ответы на команды в TelegramBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Я пишу телеграмм-бота, который кидает мемы и анекдоты. Допустим, я перехожу в анекдоты и там у меня выбор: 1)новые 2) избранные. Тоже самое, когда я перехожу в мемы, у меня выбор: 1)новые 2) избранные. Если я просто напишу:  `elif message.text == 'Избранные'` , то когда я буду просить избранные мемы и избранные анекдоты, то он будет выполнять одно и то же, а я хочу разделить для каждого свое действие. Вы можете сказать, что можно написать `elif message.text == 'Избранные мемы'` и `elif message.text == 'Избранные анекдоты'`. Можно, но у меня там еще много такого и не хочется так делать (тем более что в некоторых случаях боту нужно принимать, что пишет пользователь, а то, что пишет пользователь  может совпадать с другими командами (при этом я точно не знаю, что напишет пользователь, так что отделаться elif не могу))

Comment: Может лучше сделать кнопки(инлайн например)?

Comment: @Nobody, кнопки есть, дело не в этом, а в том, что мне нужно попросить число у пользователя в разных разделах, а это число может совпадать в разных разделах, я не знаю, как это исправить

Comment: Не знаю насколько это правильно, но можно сделать так: например кнопка - мемы, пользователь её нажимает, и в коде ставится флаг (flag = 'mem'), а дальше уже отскакивать от этого, смотреть через *if* состояние флага и для нужного состояния цифру искать

Comment: Делайте кнопками с колбэком. Там помимо текста кнопки передается поле data, в которую можно положить уникальный id для каждого подраздела. А пользователь его вообще видеть не будет.